# Cannot import Graph, Node, Relationship from py2neo

Tags: python, neo4j, py2neo

I cannot import py2neo's elements: Graph, Node, NodeSelector, Relationship

When I try to code it directly on the WinPython Commad Prompt it works just fine:

[image]

But when I type that in a file using Notepad++ and I try to run it on command prompt it dosen't work:

[image]

I have: Python 3.3.5, Neo4j 3.1.3 and py2neo 2.0.8. I had py2neo v3 before but it was not working for that version so I did a downgrade to v2 but abviously it doesn't work also for this version.

Comment: Are you sure that the python interpreter of WinPython is the same of your system python? It seem like they are two different environments...Please, check it.

Comment: @superciccio14 I've just resolved the problem, I had to change the file's location. I don't know why but it works. It seems like when I try to run it on command prompt the location where my file was was not allowing it to have access to py2neo so it can import Graph, Node, ...
It's kinda like when you want to execute a program using Eclipse you have to put it in the workspace of Eclipse.
 Is it normal?

Comment: Probably you are using different version of the interpreter. Does winPython has its own version of Python?

Comment: @superciccio14 No

Comment: from where and where did you copy the library to fix the problem?

Comment: @superciccio14 it was in Documents and I copied it to py2neo's folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand after a quick look to official [Doc](https://github.com/winpython/winpython), WinPython does create a dedicated distribution of the Python programming language for Windows with its own local settings, in fact:

> You can install as many WinPython distributions as you want on the same machine: each one is isolated and self-consistent

You installed `py2neo` in one of your WinPython environments and, as you mentioned, it works fine.

When you try to run a python script by typing: `python foo.py` you are using your system interpreter which is not aware of packages inside WinPython environments.

If you want to run files via command line, you have to install `py2neo` and all your packages in the path of your system interpreter. You can do it just by using [pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-do-i-install-pip-on-windows) (outside from the WinPython env!!) or just by roughly copying and pasting files (not recommended).

Comment: It makes sense now. Thank you for the clarifications.